# what happens when i say arrayCollection.addItemAt(object,0);

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, arraycollection

Lets say i have an Array collection, filled with some elements. If i say

```
myArrayCollection.addItemAt(object,0);
```

What exactly happens here? Does all the elements gets shifted rigthwards? or element at 0th position gets replaced with new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize, the reason there are two different methods, addItemAt() and setItemAt(), is because one of them adds a new item (not replacing any of the existing ones), and the other sets/overwrites the existing index.

For more info, check out the [ArrayCollection documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html#methodSummary).